# A 404 error occurred Page not found Zend skeleton application

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have installed the skeleton application on my system. Its working development server. But when I run the code localhost I am receiving error following type error:

```
A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

No Exception available
© 2005 - 2015 by Zend Technologies Ltd. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: You should edit your answer and write the answer that resolved your problem. It will help anyone in the future who see's it. Also vote for the person's answer who helped.

Comment: already  i have voted your answer Mayhem

Comment: I mean tick/accept, not vote.. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Cheers, was glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also ensure that Apache is configured to support .htaccess files. This is usually done by changing the setting:

1
 AllowOverride None
to

1
 AllowOverride FileInfo

for further information please visit follow the url:http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/ref/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

If i am not mistake, the .htaccess file is your issue here
Check: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

"If you see a standard Apache 404 error, then you need to fix .htaccess usage before continuing. If you’re are using IIS with the URL Rewrite Module, import the following:"

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
```

Scroll down to "Using the Apache Web Server" and its just at the bottom of that section.

- First google result for "zend skeleton 404 error"

Otherwise this page was suggest as a good starting tutorial: https://code.google.com/p/zf2notes/wiki/zf2_beginners_tutorial

Simple by the error, it sounds like the base .htaccess file is setup for routing and it either needs friendly urls/parameters or something is not being handed through the htaccess file correctly.