# Zend Skeleton Application album tutorial 404

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

As far as I can see I've followed the [Zend skeleton application tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) to the letter (I actually went through it twice with the same result) but when I try to access `zf2-tutorial.localhost/album` I get the following error:

```
A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

No Exception available
© 2005 - 2015 by Zend Technologies Ltd. All rights reserved.
```

Going to `zf2-tutorial.localhost` displays the Zend welcome page and the 404 is wrapped in the Zend styling so something at least appears to be working.

I have tried the offered solutions on similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425855/a-404-error-occurred-page-not-found-zend-skeleton-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439474/zend-framework-2-album-tutorial-404-error-occurred-the-requested-url-could-not-b) but to no avail, any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I am using running the tutorial locally on XAMPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out in module.config.php I had split the array with the controllers and router into two arrays by mistake. Combining them into one seems to have solved this particular issue.

Code follows:

```
 return array(
 'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),

  'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'album' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                         'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ), 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of problems connected with configuring server for working with zend i may recommend you installing WAMP server. Then by uploading zend files to subdirectory you will be able to start your turn with zend.

Comment: I should have noted I am already using XAMPP, edited question, thanks.

Comment: How does your .htaccess and router configuration file looks like ?

Comment: Exactly as shown in the [tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) ... Could there be anything else on my machine which could cause the issue? 

I have also ensured " AllowOverride FileInfo" in my httpd.conf is as stated in the tutorial.

Comment: And if you access normally the script using the normal path and not zf2-tutorial.localhost do you still get the same error? I remember that I had the same while using WAMP and from what I remember I just simply downloaded not the skeleton application but ready "application with album modules included". Unluckily now I can't find the files.

Comment: Using localhost/zf2-tutorial results in a standard XAMPP 404 for both the welcome page and the /album. The .htaccess provided in the other answer above is exactly the same as the one I have already implemented unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try also using the below provided .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems this error not related to .htaccess, its configuration problem. Please ensure that you've defined needed rotes in Album\config\module.config.php file:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html#routing-and-controllers

Comment: Yes I was thinking along the same lines it appears the Controller isn't executing but I can confirm the routes are as stated in the tutorial

Comment: Just tryed to reproduce your error in my test ZF2 application - I've received exactly same error if I do not define used module ( 'Users' in my case) in configs/application.comfig.php file. Check your application configs file and ensure that it contains 'modules' => array('Application', 'Album')

Comment: I can confirm 'modules' => array('Application', 'Album') exists in my /config/application.config.php and I am still getting the same error. Also double checked my directory structure to ensure that is as stated in the tutorial and all appears to be fine.